# jqgrid+knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, knockout.js

I managed to run knockout js. example: http://jsfiddle.net/brux88/9fzG4/ . now I would like to replicate the same thing using jqGrid, but I can not run the calculations in real time. can someone help me? I also tried without using knockout, but only using jqGrid I do not work the same.example: http://jsfiddle.net/brux88/yGJcy/

Answer (score 2):

You could try using this plugin
[Knockout-jqGridBinding](https://github.com/CraigCav/Knockout-jqGridBinding)

Comment: Welcome to SO! This would be a better answer if you gave an example of how to use the plugin. External links can disappear over time - code examples here have a better chance of lasting longer.

Answer (score 2):

Why reinvent the wheel, there is a good knockout grid called KoGrid, head over to their page, its full of examples and demos

https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid

Comment: i really have very little patience for github pages where examples lead to a 404. anyone got a URL that works?

Comment: The links work, but its a fork from one of the main guys behind the grid. This is the main repo https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid